# Is there a simple counterexample to étale proper base change on the unbounded derived category?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, etale-cohomology

The best non-derived version of proper base change on the étale site of a scheme I know is that for $f : X \to Y$ proper and $g : Y' \to Y$ arbitrary, the base change morphism $g^{-1} R f_\star \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow R f_\star'(g')^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism for every torsion abelian sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ in $D^+(X_\text{ét})$. Are there any easy counterexamples in this setting for complexes which are not bounded below?

Comment: I'm very far from being an expert on this, but I think you may be interested in the discussion just after Thm 7.13 on Scholze's lecture notes on Six-Functor Formalisms. (https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/SixFunctors.pdf)

Comment: Also, I would like to point out that proper base change should always hold for *arbitrary* $f$ as long as you change $f_*$ to $f_!$. (Which then reduces to what you have for proper $f$.)

Comment: @Gabriel where 'arbitrary' means finite type and separated, right?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Indeed! I was a little imprecise as my goal was to emphasise that the properness assumption is there precisely so that $f_!$ becomes isomorphic to $f_*$. In Scholze's notes, he works with a slightly more general class of maps: those separated and of "finite expansion". (See the appendix to the lecture VII for more.)

Comment: Dear @C.D. take a look in example 6.5 in A. Neeman's The Grothendieck Duality Theorem via Bousfield's Techniques and Brown Representability. There he gives a counterexample to something similar to what you want but in the context of quasi-coherent sheaves. Perhaps it's simple to adapt it to your setting...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! I have seen that example, but it seems to be essentially coherent in nature -- note that (1) the argument computes $f^!$ by identifying it with derived Hom, which as far as I know is a phenomenon specific to modules, (2) the proper morphism considered is an infinitesimal thickening. By topological invariance of the etale site, $f_\star$ is an equivalence for such maps.

Comment: Also (3), the bottom map he considers is an open immersion. Etale proper base change holds formally whenever the horizontal maps are etale maps -- the higher pushforwards are a sheafification, so compatible with restriction.

Comment: All this to say that an etale counterexample seems like it would come from a very different setting. Perhaps the bottom map could be something non-smooth over Spec k and the vertical map could be projective space...